# keyset pagination with full text search on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table 'users' with +100,000 records. I want to start making use of keyset pagination to speed up the process of fetching records.

The following query works. This query fetches the **second** page of the recordset (starting at user_id: 1001, and fetching until user_id: 2000).

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    username
FROM
    users
WHERE
    user_id > 1000
ORDER BY
    user_id ASC
LIMIT
    1000
```

The problem is: I don't want to order the records on user_id. I have a column named "tokens" which is a to_tsvector column. I want to perform full text search on the recordset and order the users on rank. The new query:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    username,
    to_tsrank(tokens, plainto_tsquery('search query')) AS rank
FROM
    users
WHERE
    tokens @@ plainto_tsquery('search query')
```

How can I apply a keyset pagination on this second query, so the results are ordered on rank instead of user_id?

**Important:**

I tried this one, but this does not work!

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    username,
    to_tsrank(tokens, plainto_tsquery('search query')) AS rank
FROM
    users
WHERE
    tokens @@ plainto_tsquery('search query')
AND
    to_tsrank(tokens, plainto_tsquery('search query')) < $1 // $1 = last fetched rank
ORDER BY
    rank DESC
LIMIT
    1000
```

Let's say, when the results are ranked on 'rank', the 1,000th result has a rank of 0.5. $1 (last fetched rank) would be 0.5, so I would select all results with rank < 0.5. The problem is: some results may have **the same** rank. So if the 1,001th record would also be rank = 0.5, it wouldn't be fetched because I say in my query `rank < 0.5`. I also cannot say `rank <= 0.5`because that would fetch the previous results with rank = 0.5 again.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide a fully deterministic ORDER BY.  Assuming user_id is unique:

```
ORDER BY rank desc, user_id
```

Then your WHERE would include:

```
AND (rank < :last_rank or (rank = :last_rank and user_id > :last_user_id))
```

But this will not be efficient, so you might as well just do OFFSET.

Better yet, don't do it at all.  No human is realistically going to read through 1000 results, and think "You know, I'd like to do this a few more times".  The only one who will do that is the web scraper, and the only reason the web scraper will do it is because it is the only method you offer.  Just let them set a LIMIT which is as high as they want, and offer no pagination.

Comment: maybe you are right. It's for an app, and users can search for other users. When they enter some text, the usernames matching the text the best will appear first. If there are multiple results, the most popular users have to come first. I think most people will not scroll down to more than 50 results. Thanks for the input!